# What is the smallest possible area for a triangle of integral side lengths whose perimeter is 15cm?

Tags: area

> What is the smallest possible area for a triangle of integral side lengths whose perimeter is 15cm? Round your decimal answer to the nearest hundredth.

How do you find this?

Comment: Think about triangle inequality and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the triangle has (integer) sides $a,b,c$ then as given $a+b+c = 15$. Now let's use imranfat's suggestion of the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality): $$a+b > c$$ $$a+c > b$$ $$b+c >a.$$

Since we want to minimize area and all our data is in terms of side lengths I think [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) is our best bet: let $s = \frac{a+b+c}{2} = 15/2 =7.5$ then the area $A$ of our triangle is $$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \sqrt{7.5(7.5-a)(7.5-b)(7.5-c)}.$$

From looking at the above one can see to make the area small we essentially want some integer, say $a$, closest to $7.5$, in particular $7$ is good because it leaves $0.5$ which scales down our area. Any integer small leaves a whole number multiply which increases the area and we can't go bigger than $7$ by the triangle inequalities and the bound on perimeter. All of which should motivate the choice of $(7,7,1)$ as our triple for $(a,b,c)$ which gives minimal area (for intuition this is a very skinny isosceles triangle). Doing the calculation and rounding gives $A \approx 3.49$.

[Note this approach isn't the most elegant, and we could be more exact by using the tools of calculus, but from a purely high-school geometry point of view it's a workable way of thinking.]

Comment: Raj's answer confirmed by simple search in *Mathematica*.

Comment: You can keep on reducing area of a triangle by reducing one of the sides and keep the perimeter same by increasing other two sides. So to use calculus, we will have to add some lower bounds and it is going to be cumbersome. This is a good way to go about this optimization problem.